# C# Mono Console : how fix first line in out put

Tags: c#, mono, console

I wanna figure a table in Console, so when I have much information in the table (like more than 20 lines), I lost table's title (**Name Date    Time    Download**)

How can I fix the 3 first lines, and

```
------------------------------------------------
Name    Date    Time    Download
------------------------------------------------
text1   28/10   13:11   not yet
text2   28/10   13:14   not yet
text3   28/10   13:19   not yet
text4   28/10   13:25   not yet
text5   28/10   13:45   not yet
text6   28/10   13:50   not yet
  .       .       .        .
  .       .       .        .
  .       .       .        .
text35  28/10   13:59   not yet
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check if you have more items than you can display, and if this is the case, stop printing the items and print your empty lines instead.

Here's a quick and dirty example:

```
void Main()
{
    var input = Enumerable.Range(1, 35).Select(e => "Line: " + e).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");
    Console.WriteLine("THE HEADER");
    Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------");

    foreach (var element in GetLines(input))
        Console.WriteLine(element);
}

IEnumerable<string> GetLines(IList<string> input, int maxLines = 10)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < input.Count; i++)
    {
        yield return input[i];

        if (i == maxLines - 5 && input.Count > maxLines)
        {
            yield return " . . . .";
            yield return " . . . .";
            yield return " . . . .";
            yield return input[input.Count - 1];
            yield break;
        }
    }
}
```

It will print

```
------------------------------------------------
THE HEADER
------------------------------------------------
Line: 1
Line: 2
Line: 3
Line: 4
Line: 5
Line: 6
 . . . .
 . . . .
 . . . .
Line: 35
```